# Unable to connect guest using VMWare Player

Tags: windows-xp, redhat, vmware-player

I'm running RedHat server 5.3 as guest on Window XP VMware palyer.
the network setting is set to "Host Only", but I have tries all other settings.

I'm able to ping the guest machine, but I'm unable to connect it in any other way including webserver, Tomcat, Telnet, ssh.
all of the services above are working from within the guest (using localhost).
Guest firewall and SELinux are disabled.

any idea on what I should check next? 
every idea will be appreciated...

thnaks 
Ilan

Comment: Changing the guest configuration from Static IP to DHCP (with "Host Only") solved the connection issue. However, I still need to use Static IP on the guest (due to applications issues), Any idea how to set VMWare to recognize the static IP?

Answer (score 1):

I've always used a "Bridged" network adapter when using VMware.  With that, the VM Guest should get a DHCP IP from your router.  And once you have that, you should be able to access it via it's own IP.

Comment: I tried using "Bridged", still same problem. tnx.